# How to implement push method in Native jsonstore app in Worklight 6.2

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, jsonstore

I was exploring recent Worklight 6.2, JSONStore in Android native is really good thing done, but I am wondering how do I implement the push functions like I used to do WOrklight JS.

I there any APIs available to achieve this or I need to to invoke the procedure manually from native app.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [working with external data section](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/?lang=en#!/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/c_jsonstore_external_data.html) of Knowledge Center for Worklight v6.2. It talks about getting data from an external source which commonly referred to as pull. It also talks about sending data back to said external source which is commonly referred to as push. In both the hybrid and native environments, you get to pick the transport layer. It could be invoke procedure from the adapter client-side API (Native iOS, Native Android, Hybrid) or it could be [NSURLConnection](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (Native iOS), jQuery.ajax (Hybrid), [HttpClient](https://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/HttpClient.html) (Native Android) or another network API.